# Should peeving disguised as question be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

As sub-question, would questions containing sentences like "it really bugs me that people keep saying [...]" be considered peeving?

Comment: Granted I'm new, but... what do you mean by peeving (as it relates to EL&U?)

Comment: _Peeving_, in this case, means a question about something that annoys, or irritates the OP.

Comment: Ah - akin to SO's technology rant disguised as questions. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as there's an actual *question* beneath the peeve, I'd allow it. Hopefully the top-voted answers will redirect the asker's futile rage.

I'd worry more about *answers* that are just an expression of personal peeves, but the community is very good about voting those down.

Comment: I agree. As long as there is a decent question in it, it could be interesting for visitors from the internets, which is what it should all be about, shouldn't it? In addition, an intelligent rant might benefit the literary quality of the question, and actually make it a *better* read. Dry questions aren't always the "best" in all aspects.

Answer (score 4):

Per

https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - It is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: Well yes, a question that is merely a peeve/rant is always closed as "not a real question". I think this meta question here is about something that *does* contain an actual question about English, merely tainted by a disguised peeve. :-)

Comment: @Shree: I think you are absolutely right. The description in the FAQ doesn't necessarily cover the kind of question we are talking about here.

Comment: On second thought, it DOES cover the kind of peeve question that Kiam's meta-question is about; but JSBangs's answer complicates the matter, the right way.